# Alerting several different variables but new line won't work

Tags: javascript

```
alert("The sum is" + sum\n"The multiplication is" + multiply\n"The division is" + division\n"The modulo is" + modulo\n"The subtraction is" + subtract);
```

In the above code, I've declared the variables properly however new lines just won't display.

Comment: Your `\n`s need to go inside the quotes. `alert("The sum is" + sum + "\nThe multiplication.....`

Comment: Also you could use [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (string interpolation) using backticks `\`The sum is ${sum}\nThe multiplication is ${multiply}\n...\`` so you don't have to keep opening and closing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` should be within the quotation marks.